# How to do animate function during a animate function?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a stylish search function, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. But I just can't explain you the whole code but you see the Problem Demo page (link at bottom). The problem is when a user enters a string in the search query I want dynamically search for a keyword matching the string and show the results on a drop down (fading) `div` element, using `Ajax` and `PHP`. But currently there is no such function in it. but I have just add a framework type example content in that `div` element.

So when a users enters a string the `div` element fades in but when the user take the mouse over it, it just gets faded out. I don't know what the problem is. So please view the Problem Demo page and see the code, but I have posted the Jquery code below too, for just help. But for HTML code you have to view this page. Can anyone help me out with this one, and if you want more info tell me I will provide.

---

```
<html> 
<head> 
      head including scripts here......
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
              $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('div#search-bar').mouseover(function() {
                      $(this).stop().animate({ opacity : '1.0', top : '51px' },200,'linear',function () {
                         $('input.search-textbox', this).focus();
                      });
                      $('div.site-select span img').stop().animate({ opacity : '0.5' },200,'linear',function () {});
                      $('img.search-button').stop().animate({ opacity : '0.6' },200,'linear',function () {});
                  });
                  $('div#search-bar').mouseout(function() {
                      $(this).stop().animate({ opacity : '0.9', top : '60px' },200,'linear',function (e) {
                         $('input.search-textbox', this).blur();
                         $('div.search-keywords-framework').css('opacity','0.0').stop();
                      });
                      $('div.site-select span img').stop().animate({ opacity : '0.2' },200,'linear',function () {});
                      $('img.search-button').stop().animate({ opacity : '0.4' },200,'linear',function () {});
                  });
                  $('input.search-textbox').keyup(function (e) {
                      if ($('div.search-keywords-framework').css('opacity')==0)
                      {
                        $('div.search-keywords-framework').animate({ opacity : '1.0' },200,'linear',function () {$(this).stop();});
                      }
                  });
                  $('div.search-keywords-framework').mouseover(function () {
                      $('div#search-bar').css('opacity','1.0');
                  });
                  $('div.search-keywords-framework').click(function () {
                      $('div#search-bar').css('opacity','1.0');
                  });
                  $('div.site-select span img.prev').mouseover(function () {
                      $(this).animate({ opacity : '1.0' },200,'linear',function () { $(this).stop(); });
                  });
                  $('div.site-select span img.next').mouseover(function () {
                      $(this).animate({ opacity : '1.0' },200,'linear',function () { $(this).stop(); });
                  });
                  $('div.site-select span img').mouseout(function () {
                      $(this).animate({ opacity : '0.5' },100,'linear',function () { $(this).stop(); });
                  });
                  $('div.site-select span img.next').click(function () {
                      $(this).animate({ opacity : '1.0' },100,'linear',function () { });
                  });
                  $('div.site-select span img.prev').click(function () {
                      $(this).animate({ opacity : '1.0' },100,'linear',function () { });
                  });
                  $('img.search-button').mouseover(function () {
                      $(this).animate({ opacity : '1.0' },100,'linear',function () { $(this).stop(); });
                  });
                  $('img.search-button').mouseout(function () {
                      $(this).animate({ opacity : '0.6' },250,'linear',function () { $(this).stop(); });
                  });

                   $('div.site-select div.select-frame').cycle({
                        fx:     'fade',
                        speed:   500,
                        prev:   'div.site-select span img.prev',
                        next:   'div.site-select span img.next',
                        timeout: 0,
                        pause:   1,
                        cleartype:  true,
                        before:  selectsitetext,
                        after:   selectsitetext
                   });

                  function selectsitetext() {
                      $('div.site-select input#select-site-text').val($(this).text());
                  }

                  $('a.menu-button').mouseover(function () {
                     $('img.over',this).stop().animate({ opacity : '1.0' },200,'linear',function () {});
                  });
                  $('a.menu-button').mouseout(function () {
                     $('img.over',this).stop().animate({ opacity : '0.0' },150,'linear',function () {});
                     $('img.click',this).stop().animate({ opacity : '0.0' },150,'linear',function () {});
                  });
                  $('a.menu-button').click(function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     $('img.click',this).stop().animate({ opacity : '1.0' },100,'linear',function () {});
                  });

              });
      </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
      other header framework here............
                                                   <div id="search-bar"> 
                                                          <table width="500px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
                                                                  <tbody> 
                                                                          <tr> 
                                                                               <td class="search-frame-base-textbox-left"></td> 
                                                                               <td class="search-frame-base-textbox-mid"> 
                                                                                    <input type="textbox" class="search-textbox" /> 
                                                                                    <div class="search-keywords-framework" style="position: absolute; z-index: 500; margin: 0px 0px 0px -30px; opacity: 0.0;"> 
                                                                                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="350px" style="font-family: Droid Sans; font-size: 12px;"> 
                                                                                                  <tbody> 
                                                                                                          <tr> 
                                                                                                               <td style="background:url('img/search-keyword-bsae-top-left.png');width:17px;height:17px;background-repeat:no-repeat;"></td> 
                                                                                                               <td style="background:url('img/search-keyword-bsae-top-mid.png');height:17px;background-repeat:repeat-x;"></td> 
                                                                                                               <td style="background:url('img/search-keyword-bsae-top-right.png');width:17px;height:17px;background-repeat:no-repeat;"></td> 
                                                                                                          </tr> 
                                                                                                          <tr> 
                                                                                                               <td style="background:url('img/search-keyword-bsae-mid-left.png');width:17px;background-repeat:repeat-y;"></td> 
                                                                                                               <td style="background: rgb(242,242,242);"> 
                                                                                                                     <div style="padding: 5px 5px; width: 100%;"><a href="#" style="color: #333; text-decoration: none; font-size: 12px;">Search Demo 1</a><font style="float: right; background: #333; color: #fff; font-size: 10px; padding: 2px 5px; margin-right: 10px;">26</font></div> 
                                                                                                                     <br> 
                                                                                                                     And much more similiar keywords...........
                                                                                                               </td> 
                                                                                                               <td style="background:url('img/search-keyword-bsae-mid-right.png');width:17px;background-repeat:repeat-y;"></td> 
                                                                                                          </tr> 
                                                                                                          <tr> 
                                                                                                               <td style="background:url('img/search-keyword-bsae-bottom-left.png');width:17px;height:17px;background-repeat:no-repeat;"></td> 
                                                                                                               <td style="background:url('img/search-keyword-bsae-bottom-mid.png');height:17px;background-repeat:repeat-x;"></td> 
                                                                                                               <td style="background:url('img/search-keyword-bsae-bottom-right.png');width:17px;height:17px;background-repeat:no-repeat;"></td> 
                                                                                                          </tr> 
                                                                                                  </tbody> 
                                                                                          </table> 
                                                                                    </div> 
                                                                               </td> 
                                                                               <td class="search-frame-base-textbox-right"></td> 
                                                                               <td class="search-frame-base-site-bg"> 
                                                                                    <div class="site-select"> 
                                                                                        <div class="select-frame"> 
                                                                                             <font>All</font> 
                                                                                             <font>Games</font> 
                                                                                             <font>Music</font> 
                                                                                             <font>Videos</font> 
                                                                                        </div> 
                                                                                        <span class="search-select-sites-nav-frame"> 
                                                                                              <img width="25px" height="21px" class="next" src="img/search-frame-base-site-trigger-close.png" /> 
                                                                                              <img width="25px" height="21px" class="prev" src="img/search-frame-base-site-trigger.png" /> 
                                                                                        </span> 
                                                                                        <input type="hidden" id="select-site-text" /> 
                                                                                    </div> 
                                                                               </td> 
                                                                               <td class="search-frame-base-site-sep"></td> 
                                                                               <td class="search-frame-base-button-bg"> 
                                                                                    <img width="28px" height="30px" class="search-button" src="img/search-frame-base-button.png" /> 
                                                                               </td> 
                                                                          </tr> 
                                                                  </tbody> 
                                                          </table> 
                                                   </div> 
                                              </td> 
                                         </tr> 
                                 </tbody> 
                         </table> 
                     </td> 
       footer framework...........
</body> 
</html>
```

---

**[PROBLEM SOLUTION](http://wooflux.co.cc/01/)**

Comment: Quote the relevant code **in** the question. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you, and external resources can get moved, deleted, modified, etc. StackOverflow is meant to be helpful, not just right now for you, but for others with a similar issue down-the- line.

Comment: Sorry, buddy but the code is too long to be inserted but if you want here you go.

Comment: When I move the mouse over the div `search-keywords-framework`, it's ok. But when I move the mouse out of it, or out of the search input, it disappears. I think the problem is in the input, because when I move the mouse out of it, it loses the focus event.

Comment: @Jack: *"Sorry, buddy but the code is too long"* Then it's your job to boil it down to the essentials.

Comment: Ok, I will do it, just give me some time.

Comment: oi vey, this begs for major refactoring - define reusable functions, do NOT use tables for element positioning.

Comment: Sorry, can't resist :D - ['*Yo dawg, I herd you like animations so I put an animate function in your animate function so you can animate while you animate!*'](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg)

Comment: I don't know but what is wrong with that link buddy!~no.good.at.coding

Comment: Hey, the code have been shortened, so anyone is interested in answering this one or I have to do it myself? ~ all

Comment: You can answer it yourself? Please do then!

Comment: I'm on it, I'm finding the solution.

Comment: I have found it and stetted the Fading Out of the Main Search Bar on clicking the `body` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would **strongly** recommend ditching the tables. If it is not meant to been displayed as a table, there shouldn't be one. I wouldn't be surprised if some of the problems came from this fact.

That said, as far as I see, the problem arises when the cursor hovers `div.menu-bar-base-small` which is overlapping the `div#search-bar`. If you restructurate your code to a more simple block/level architecture with no overlappings (and no tables), and use `position:absolute` only when it is absolutely necessary, I am sure the problem will disappear by itself.

For example you now have:

```
<table>
    <td> <div> logo </div> </td>
    <td> <div> search </div> </td>
</table>
<div class="menu-bar-base-small" style="position:absolute">...</div>
```

Should look more like

```
<div>
    <div> logo </div>
    <div> search </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-bar-base-small" style="position:relative">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer buddy but I have change my approach and set the fade out of the main search bar on clicking the body of the HTML Document. But a vote up for this answer and also accepting it, as your code works!